# Expanding a post area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, expand

Here's a finished design:

[image]

Here's a (broken) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rlesko/f3R7r/4/

Can I use HTML5 or js or anything so that when you click the "Expand >>" text, the white background expands to the right something like 200px? And when it's expanded, the text changes to "<< Contract" and does the opposite? The title and paragraph text should expand as well, following the white background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, expanding on your fiddle, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/f3R7r/23/) is roughly what you'll be looking at. And to animate it instead, you can just use the [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

But there are a lot more efficient ways to accomplish what your doing. Unless you have a specific reason for formatting the page in that manor (which is entirely possible given this looks like an extracted test case) I would make the inner div width relevant to the outer div plus some margin, and then expand the outer div instead. The same goes for your header. Instead of using a width, I'd try margin on the left and right to get the effect your going for so dynamic resizing is easier.

Comment: Yeah, that is exactly what I wanted.
I will use it as a mean of getting the post to show full-screen.
I will use it on a single post page but the complete design has a sidebar on the right and I would like to have that sidebar disappear after the click action and the post area expands to the right where the sidebar was.
Thanks, your code will surely help!

Comment: James Johnson, don't know whether you'll see this answer or not but if you do, please tell me where I can find those codes you posted as the answer before removing it. Or at least tell me what to search for when looking for those. Cheers!

Comment: Ktash, I added the js code and .expanded class (to CSS) to my site and it doesn't work. Don't know why, any ideas? Did I miss something?

Comment: I'd check the classes and selectors to make sure those are right. Also, make sure the `.expanded` class is declared either after the class with the width in the CSS, or has an `!important` flag on it.

Comment: When I copy/paste my HTML, CSS and js to fiddle, it works but when I use it in the complete design, it doesn't work!
May I send you my whole web site code (in private) so that you can see why that expand doesn't work?

Comment: Go for it. My email is in my profile. You can also send a link and I can check it out if you have it live somewhere.